# Настройка Pycharm окна вывода

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть ли настройка в Pycharm, что бы в окне вывода не отображалась служебная информация. Только результат выполнения кода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не думаю что есть такая настройка. Да и думается мне что это желание есть простой каприз без какой либо адекватной причины кроме как "хочется".

Comment: Ну, а почему бы нет... (если хочется) в vs code в плагине Code Runner есть такая возможность... :)